# how can add map object to list object non static in java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, non-static

I have problem with this code,when I add map object to list,all previous added object will be changed.how can I declare map as non static?

```
for(Statment){
   map.put(Key,value),                 
 }            
 result.add(map);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is Java?:p

Comment: What do you mean by "non static" ?

Comment: please add details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add something to a container, you are adding the reference (not a copy of the object it references) If you want to add a copy (so that if you can change the original, and the copy added to the list does not change) you have to explicitly copy it.

e.g.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   map.put(i, i);
list.add(new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>(map)); // add a copy.
// you can change map without the list changing as well.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for (condition) {
   if (!map.containskey(key)) {
       map.put(key,value);
   }                 
}            
result.add(map);
```

Comment: Even though the question does not make much sense, this is most probably what he means.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare each object outside the `for` otherwise  you are adding just one reference, and any modification modifies all.